# how to print CSV values from bash script when values have spaces

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, eval

I have the following **CSV** files ( I have linux red-hat 6.2 version )

```
# more  SIMPLE_FILES.CSV
  FILE1,FILE2,FILE3
  /etc/hosts,/etc/info.txt,/var/log.txt
  /etc/some_file,/var/collect.txt,/etc/INFO.txt
  /sbin/ls,/sbin/awk,/sbin/sed

 # more COMPLEX_FILES.CSV
   FILE1,FILE2,FILE3
   /etc/config/net ip.txt,/var/log/summary snap/LOG OF global/info.txt
   /etc/hosts files hosts.info/etc/hosts,var/log/messages,/sbin/collect file/all.info
   /etc/old/TEXT INFO/info.txt/etc/OLD FILES/info.txt,/root/customor select/info.txt
```

the following bash script should read the CSV file and print the files PATH for **FILE1,FILE2,FILE3**

remark - I set the param **CSV_LINE=2** only for example ( the second values in CSV )

```
 #!/bin/bash


 CSV=SIMPLE_FILES.CSV

 CSV_LINE=2

 eval $(awk -v A=$CSV_LINE -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
            NR==A { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=" $i; exit }' $CSV  )


 echo $FILE1
 echo $FILE2
 echo $FILE3
```

so if I run the bash script ( when I set **CSV=SIMPLE_FILES.CSV** )  get the following

```
 /read_path_from_csv.bash


 /etc/hosts
 /etc/info.txt
 /var/log.txt
```

until now its fine,

but if I run the bash script ( when I set **CSV=COMPLEX_FILES.CSV** )  get the follwoiojng

```
  ./read_path_from_csv.bash: line 20: ip.txt: command not found
```

My conclusion - its seems that the spaces in the PATH cause for this error

please advice how to update my code in order to print the PATH as defined in the **COMPLEX_FILES.CSV** ,

How to add one **"** before PATH and one **"** after the PATH ?

Example what I **should** to get:

```
/read_path_from_csv.bash

/etc/config/net ip.txt,/var/log/summary snap/LOG OF global/info.txt
/etc/hosts files hosts.info/etc/hosts,var/log/messages,/sbin/collect file/all.info
/etc/old/TEXT INFO/info.txt/etc/OLD FILES/info.txt,/root/customor select/info.txt
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between COMPLEX_FILES.csv input and output, apart from the fact 1st line is not printed. Could you indicate so?

Comment: the first line shuld not printed because they the parameters , we want to print only the values from the second line until end

Comment: Then why not just `awk 'NR>1' file`? It is still not clear what you want and definitely using `eval` looks a bit odd.

Comment: awk 'NR>1' print only the values , but what I need is to set the values in to the parameters that defined in the first line in the CSV    ( parameters shuld be print in side the bash script )

Comment: Let me know if you have other idea

Comment: Now it is fine. What I recommend is to try to find a better way to explain it, because it was not very clear. At least to me! Good to read that you could solve it, though.

Comment: yes thx , if you agree I will happy to get one UPVOTE -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it the spaces in the PATH that causing this problem, and you can add quotes to avoid it.

```
eval $(awk -v A=$CSV_LINE -v q='"' -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
            NR==A { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=" q $i q; exit }' $CSV)
```

**Explanation:**

If you run `eval 'FILE1=/path/file name'` in bash, it will give an error:

```
-bash: name: command not found
```

And you can quotes the `/path/file name` part to avoid this error:

```
> eval 'FILE1="/path/file name"'
> echo $FILE1
/path/file name
```

Comment: YES GOOD SOLUTION I AGREE   ( +1 and UPVOTE )